# Android: How to handle when "adb restore" on my app has finished?

Tags: android

Is it possible for my app to handle the events of when backup and restore has finished, via `adb backup` and `adb restore`? I would like to check the integrity of my files when restore has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. This is run by a system service and you won't get notified about it. If integrity of the files matters to you, you should probably check on each start or periodically.